# Setting a WiFi router as WiFi extender (Only IPv6 working)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ipv6

I am planning to use an old WiFi router as a WiFi extender
I have configured everything on the router. The DHCP server is off, channel mode is set to bridged and Universal Repeater Mode is enabled. However, when I try to connect it to my Linux machine,Only IPv6 is working IPv4 is not working, and when I try to connect it to my Android phone, there is no internet at all. I have tried assigning static IP's, but it did not help.
And I also found this post on Askubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025008/ipv6-is-working-but-ipv4-isnt to get things temporarily work on linux but I found no option to get things working on my phone

Here is the terminal output when I try to ping two different sites

```
ping superuser.com
PING superuser.com (104.18.43.79) 56(84) bytes of data.
From _gateway (192.168.1.25) icmp_seq=1 Destination Net Unreachable
From _gateway (192.168.1.25) icmp_seq=2 Destination Net Unreachable
From _gateway (192.168.1.25) icmp_seq=3 Destination Net Unreachable
From _gateway (192.168.1.25) icmp_seq=4 Destination Net Unreachable
^C
--- superuser.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4007ms
```

and when I ping google

```
ping google.com
PING google.com(maa03s47-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4007:82c::200e)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from maa03s47-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4007:82c::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=100 ms
64 bytes from maa03s47-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4007:82c::200e): icmp_seq=2 ttl=116 time=103 ms
64 bytes from maa03s47-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4007:82c::200e): icmp_seq=3 ttl=116 time=49.4 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 49.371/84.182/102.739/24.633 ms
```

Could somebody please help me solve this? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.